# User Firebase Phone Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is it possible to use Phone Auth just to verify a phone number? My users are already logged in with other providers. I only need to make sure that the number they have entered is valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Firebase's PhoneAuthProvider which will send sms of one time code to the user phone number through which the user is verified.

The implementation is given in this documentation: [Firebase phone authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth)

Comment: Do your know of any restrictions if I don't sing in the user with the phone credentials?

Comment: You still need to sign-in the user to complete the phone verification process. Generating a credential doesn't necessarily mean the user's phone number is verified as they could provide a random verification code.

Answer (score 0):

lets say that You can't verify the phone number  without creating a new user linked to this number in firebase using the manual verification 
but you can unlink the phone from the user account soon after, by calling:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().
                            unlink(PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(this);
```

just like:

```
    final PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVerificationId, scode);

    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().
                        unlink(PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(this);

                register_user(sname,semail,sphone,scode, spass); // this if you wanna register with a different method
            }
        }
    });
```

And There is the possibility of auto verification of Google Play Services (in the new phones). When `onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential)` in your `PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks` is called. and here the verification is completed with no need from the user to type anything and the phone will not linked to a new user account.

```
PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(sphone, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AuthActivity.this, new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
        register_user(sname,semail,sphone,scode, spass); // this if you wanna register with a different method
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(String verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {



        // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
        mVerificationId = verificationId;
        mResendToken = token;

        // ...
    }

});
```

I think that google should allow to the developers to verify the phone without creating user account that will be so helpful